# Payslip for UK Visitor Visa Sponsor

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My brother-in-law is sponsoring my trip. However, the company he is working at is not issuing any payslip. Will the Verification of Employment Letter and Bank Statements be enough to prove his employment and income?

Comment: The employment verification letter should state his salary.